# Node.js External API requests within a GET request with api key

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, express

I am working with Node.js and I am having an issue doing a GET request within a GET request to an external API. Where I seem to be having issues is with the API key but I am not 100% sure. When I make the request, I am only returned an empty JSON object with a 200 status code. I have  What am I doing wrong?

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const request = promisify(require('request'));
const apiURL = "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2";



router.get('/lists', async(req, res) => {

  try {
    request.get({
        url: 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/lists',
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
            "api_key": */omitted for security/*
        }

    }, ( error, response, body) => {
          const data = JSON.parse(body)
        res.send(body)
    })
      
  } catch (error) {
      res.send(error)
  }
})
 



module.exports = router
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
const request = promisify(require('request'));
const apiURL = "https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2";



router.get('/lists', async(req, res) => {
  const param ="?api_key=your_api_key";

  try {
    request.get({
        url: 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/v2/lists'+param,
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json"
        }

    }, ( error, response, body) => {
          const data = JSON.parse(body)
        res.send(body)
    })
      
  } catch (error) {
      res.send(error)
  }
})
 



module.exports = router
```